# How to get rows having certain difference?

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite

If I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP (id1 int, id2 int, val int)

INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES(0, 0, 0)
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES(0, 1, 1)
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES(0, 2, 2)
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES(0, 3, 3)
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES(0, 4, 4)
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES(0, 5, 5)
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES(1, 0, 0)
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES(1, 1, 1)
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES(1, 2, 2)
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES(1, 3, 3)
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES(1, 4, 4)
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES(1, 5, 5)
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES(2, 0, 0)
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES(2, 1, 1)
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES(2, 2, 2)
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES(3, 0, 0)
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES(3, 1, 1)
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES(3, 2, 2)
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES(3, 3, 3)
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES(3, 4, 4)
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES(3, 5, 5)
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES(4, 0, 0)
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES(4, 1, 1)
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES(4, 2, 2)

DROP TABLE #TEMP
```

I am trying to get all unique `id1`'s where two given `id1`'s can have a specific difference (from the third column). Currently, I have added an index on id1 and id2 and have written a query like this:

```
SELECT X.id1 
FROM #TEMP X 
INNER JOIN #TEMP Y
ON (X.id2 = Y.id2)
AND (X.id1 = 2 AND Y.id1 = 3) // numbers are only for illustration
AND (Y.val - X.val = 1)
```

This query is currently taking 4 seconds to run on a table containing 18M records. Is there anyway to speed this up?

Comment: Have you an index on the three cols?

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa: I have an index on `id1` and `id2`. Pardon my ignorance but why is an index on `val` needed?

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa: So I tried it anyway but did not find a noticeable difference.

Comment: By the time you index all columns in a table the index is the *same* as the table effectively on disk and thus offers no extra performance.

Answer (score 1):

I would drop the indexes and try and create an index on val only.  This is the part that decides what should be returned.  It might encourage the optimizer to evaluate the difference first thus only then joining there after where the difference is known to be 1 as oppose to joining all the data first only to find the difference was not 1 so that was a wasted operation.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's executing the inner join over the entire table, and then applying the `where` clause to it.  That would result in a 18Mx18M = 324M table, which could take 4 seconds.

Do you have [statistics](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_analyze.html) in your SQLite database?

Have you tried to force use of the index with the [indexed by](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_indexedby.html) keyword?

Try to use a correlated subquery, like:

```
select  x.id1
from    #TEMP x
where   x.id1 = 2 and
        (
        select  y.val
        from    #TEMP y
        where   y.id1 = 3
                and y.id2 = x.id2
        )
        - X.val = 1
```

Perhaps this will get executed with index seeks only.

Answer (score 0):

This query seems to be deeply flawed (to put it politely) ...

```
SELECT X.id1 
FROM #TEMP X 
INNER JOIN #TEMP Y
ON (X.id2 = Y.id2)
AND (X.id1 = 2 AND Y.id1 = 3) // numbers are only for illustration
AND (Y.val - X.val = 1)
```

It can be summarised as

```
SELECT X.id1 LABORIOUSLY FRON a_pile_of_stuff WHERE X.id1 = 2
```

and in any case if you have an index on (id1, id2) it should run very quickly. I suggest that you carefully review your code and your timings. Something doesn't gel.